# FCM Notifications - how to change Icon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm newbie on using FCM API for push notifications, but the documentation didn't seem very clear for me. I'm trying to find out what values are accepted by the `notification` data content. So far, I'm trying to use it on this way:

```
        const data: NotificationData = {
            notification : {
                title: "Test Notification",
                body: "Test Notification Body",
                icon: "http://localhost:3001/gmp-icon.png"
            },
            to: window.FCMToken,
        }
```

I'm posting it against the API url https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send, and I wanted to format it as a web notification, but posteriorly as Android and iOS to be used from react-native.

Where should I add the icon value?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add an object in the body as "data" and this object will have the custom fields you want to send. And send the icon property in the data object. For ex:

```
{
"to" : "Token",
"notification" : {
    "title": "Title of the notification",
    "body": "Body of the notification",
    "data": {
      "click_action": "https://google.com",
      "customData": "valueOfCutomData",
      "image": "Some valid url",
      "icon": "Url of the icon",
      "url": "https://google.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work, still showing Chrome's icon when push is received...

Comment: Can you please check that how you receive it? I mean there are two objects passed from backend one is notification and second is data. And if you log both objects you should see all the keys passed from backend. And if data have the icon property and notification not and you passing the notification object to show. Then add the icon property in the notification object to show. Let me know if it still not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

download png file and place file in android/app/src/main/res/drawable as notification_icon.png

```
<meta-data 
         android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
         android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually putting that in a javascript call from a react app...  my aim would be showing the icon first on chrome notifications...